# Dielectric coaxial resonator vco circuits topology?

Tags: microwave, oscillator

I came across this VCO that uses a dielectric coaxial resonator, I understand how the resonator works, what I don't know is the oscillator topology, Colpitts, Clapp, et. Also I do not see any circuit element that is feeding back the output to the input, I suspect that it does so through the internal capacity of the transistor but I am not sure.
The transistor is an at42086 and the VCO frequency is 1450Mhz.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Agreed... Where is this diagram from?  With $R_E$ bypassed to ground and the base bias bypassed there's no simple feedback path. Why is $R_E$ split into 100 and 47.5 Ohm? Datasheet says S12 is -25 dB, and $C_{CB}$ is 0.32 pF so it's probably not that.

Comment: @tomnexus The circuit is working in a commercial microwave equipment. I am researching the subject at the moment, so what I am reading is studied with the concept of negative resistance oscillator.

Comment: @tomnexus R=74.5 and 10uF is a low pass filter for the power supply.  It is very common to see this as a filter in commercial circuits

Comment: more in this post https://www.eevblog.com/forum/rf-microwave/dielectric-coaxial-resonator-vco-circuits-topology/

Comment: Ah, so two big differences: the unlabelled C are just a few pF, so ~ 25 Ohm. Normally I'd assume an unlabeled C to be 10 nF so ~0 Ohm at operating frequency. And the base bias network is only 3.3k there, not 15k. Between these I can see how it achieves $S_{11}$ > 1 and the rest follows. Have you simulated this circuit?

Comment: @tomnexus I added a photo of the circuit, I have not simulated it. With a resistance of 15K in the base the circuit works well in 1450Mhz. What I want to do is make it oscillate at 1090Mhz without changing the resonator, just adding a capacitor in parallel as seen in the photo, but it doesn't work. I'm going to try lowering the base R to 3K. How do you know that $S_ {11}$ > 1?

Comment: Your link describes the design process. $S_{11}$ is of the amplifier part. But read the whole pdf carefully. The amplifier has a broad peak response, from maybe 1000-2500 MHz. The resonator is what ultimately determines the frequency of oscillation. Changing the L and C values will only slightly affect the phase noise, startup time etc. Is 1090 within the pulling range of the original VCO?

Comment: @tomnexus The original VCO has a range of 50Mhz around 1450Mhz approx. My intention is to lower it to 1090Mhz open loop and then modify the PLL in some way.

Comment: Maybe ask a new question on electronics.stackexchange, specifically about how to adjust the resonator. Perhaps it can be pulled 33% with a C, but likely not; 5% seems like a lot already. Perhaps you also need to tweak the output circuit, maybe not.